# Calling JavaScript function at the end of button click event

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, code-behind

How do you call a JavaScript function at the end of button click event in code behind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to JavaScript function from code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788330/passing-arguments-to-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're working in .NET you could try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(myButton, this.GetType(), "BlockName", "alert('hello world');", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want the onmouseup event:

```
<button onmouseup="alert('You release the mouse button!')">Click me</button>
```