# Passing arguments to JavaScript function from code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, code-behind

I would like to call a javascript function from an aspx control.  For instance, suppose I had:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(x, y)
    {

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
         onclick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff (really going to a database to fill x and y)
    int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] y = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // call javascript function as test(x,y);
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This question is similar, but not quite the same.  In my question, I am being more specific about how to pass arguments to the javascript function, and supplying example code.  I'm interested in the specific mechanics of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method.

Comment: How does it work? I need to call a JavaScript function from codebehind without any parameters, but I don't see how to use this :S

Answer (score 10):

Look at the [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method if you're using a ScriptManager or any Ajax controls/asynchronous postbacks.

Edit:

Actually, the function you want is probably [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Some other things I found out:

You can't directly pass in an array like:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "xx",   
"<script>test("+x+","+y+");</script>");
```

because that calls the ToString() methods of x and y, which returns "System.Int32[]", and obviously Javascript can't use that.  I had to pass in the arrays as strings, like "[1,2,3,4,5]", so I wrote a helper method to do the conversion.

Also, there is a difference between this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() and this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock() - the former places the script at the bottom of the page, which I need in order to be able to access the controls (like with document.getElementByID).  RegisterClientScriptBlock() is executed before the tags are rendered, so I actually get a Javascript error if I use that method.

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Manipulating-ASP-NET-Pages-and-Server-Controls-with-JavaScript.id-310803.html covers the difference between the two pretty well.

Here's the complete example I came up with:

```
// code behind
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] y = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    string xStr = getArrayString(x); // converts {1,2,3,4,5} to [1,2,3,4,5]
    string yStr = getArrayString(y);

    string script = String.Format("test({0},{1})", xStr, yStr);
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
    "testFunction", script, true);
    //this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
    //"testFunction", script, true); // different result
}
private string getArrayString(int[] array)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(array[i] + ",");
    }
    string arrayStr = string.Format("[{0}]", sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
    return arrayStr;
}

//aspx page
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(x, y)
    {
        var text1 = document.getElementById("text1")
        for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++)
        {
            text1.innerText += x[i]; // prints 12345
        }
        text1.innerText += "\ny: " + y; // prints y: 1,2,3,4,5

    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
         onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id ="text1"> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to pass objects/arrays to your clientside javascript, you could look into ASP.NET & JSON (using a hiddenfield in your HTML). A good tutorial on ASP.NET & JSON is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

Answer (score 3):

**include script manager**

**code behind function**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "HideConfirmBox", "javascript:HideAAConfirmBox(); ", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Write("<scrip" + "t>test(" + x + "," + y + ");</script>");
```

breaking up the script keyword because VStudio / asp.net compiler doesn't like it

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Call java script function on Code behind</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    function abc()
    {
        var a=20;
        var b=30;
        alert("you enter"+a+":"+b);
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return abc();");
}
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to execute the javascript serverside and not in the browser after post-back, right?

That's not possible as far as I know

If you just want to get it execute after postback, you can do something like this:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "xx", "<script>test("+x+","+y+");</script>");
```

Comment: I am looking for client side execution after post back, sorry for not being more clear.  So with this methodology, this would call an existing script on the page, correct?

Comment: yes a javascript function called "test" will be executed immediatly after postback. This is useful for showing alert popups to the user.

from googling:
"ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock is used to make sure a specific script is included in the header part of the page. The type and key parameters helps ensure that a given script is included only once even if RegisterClientScriptBlock is called multiple time for the same script (provided the same type and key)."

Comment: I seem to have posted the wrong method before. You need "RegisterClientScriptBlock". (I edited it in my post)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in processing Javascript ***on the server***, there is a new open source library called [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) that allows you to execute server side Javascript.  Basically it is a Javascript interpreter written in C#.  I have been testing it and so far it looks quite promising.

Here's the description from the site:

> Differences with other script engines:
>
> Jint is different as it doesn't use
> CodeDomProvider technique which is
> using compilation under the hood and
> thus leads to memory leaks as the
> compiled assemblies can't be unloaded.
> Moreover, using this technique
> prevents using dynamically types
> variables the way JavaScript does,
> allowing more flexibility in your
> scripts. On the opposite, Jint embeds
> it's own parsing logic, and really
> interprets the scripts. Jint uses the
> famous ANTLR (http://www.antlr.org)
> library for this purpose. As it uses
> Javascript as its language you don't
> have to learn a new language, it has
> proven to be very powerful for
> scripting purposes, and you can use
> several text editors for syntax
> checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test(x, y) 
        {
            var cc = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
            {
                cc += x[i]; 
            }
            cc += "\ny: " + y; 
            return cc;
        }

    </script>



</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"   />

        <p>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"  Name="TextBox1"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>



    </form>
</body>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] y = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    string xStr = getArrayString(x); // converts {1,2,3,4,5} to [1,2,3,4,5]
    string yStr = getArrayString(y);

    string script = String.Format(" var y = test({0},{1}) ; ", xStr, yStr);
    script += String.Format("  document.getElementById(\"TextBox1\").value = y  ");

    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),  "testFunction", script, true);
  //  this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "testFunction", script, true); // different result
}




private string getArrayString(int[] array)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(array[i] + ",");
    }
    string arrayStr = string.Format("[{0}]", sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
    return arrayStr;
}
```