# Call javascript from vb.net code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

How can I call a javascript function from code behind?
The most popular response is "`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`" however, that does not work in my situation.

I have a vb class that is doing a database check to see if a record exists. If exists, then call a javascript function to display an alert("Record exists")

So I am doing something like

```
Dim strMessage as string = "javascript:RecordExists('Param');"
```

How do I call this function from my vb.net class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments to JavaScript function from code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788330/passing-arguments-to-javascript-function-from-code-behind)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
If DataStore.Record.Exists(theRecord) Then

    Dim script As String = "alert('Record exists')"
    If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartUpScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "alertscript") Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", script, True)

    End If
End If
```

you would do it like above, where you should replaceDataStore.Record.Exists(theRecord) with condition that checks database record exists

Comment: when I attempt to use your solution, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at "If Not Page.ClientScript....."

Comment: error message: 'Page' is not a member of 'System.Web.HttpContext'.

Comment: Mistakes in the previous post:<br/>
If DataStore.Record.Exists(theRecord) Then<br/> Dim script As String = "alert('Record exists');"<br/> If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartUpScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "alertscript") Then<br/> Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", script, True)<br/> End If<br/>
End If

Comment: Is there any way to call javascript function that is already written on front end, i mean at aspx file. I just want to make call to that function from code behind.

Answer (score 11):

You need to think about your script in a slightly different way - remember, JavaScript runs client-side, and VB.NET runs server-side. So you can't "call" JavaScript from the server side.

However, you can ***generate*** JavaScript on the server side, but it will need to be output to the page before it can run.

If you were doing a full page postback, a crude way of achieving it would be to assign the script or function to a `Literal` control, which renders its `Text` property on the HTML page exactly as written.

Then, your script will execute at the point the `Literal` is rendered.

A neater way of doing it is to add your script to the page via a `ScriptManager` as you noted. Rather than a `StartupScript`, you could try using `.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` instead? You don't mention what it is about your situation that doesn't work?

The most comprehensive way of doing it would be to use AJAX - either .NET's built-in framework, or jQuery. jQuery's AJAX (and AJAX in general) is a separate topic, which you can read about [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: prohibited from using JQuery...  :-(

Comment: That's OK - it's just a nice-to-have. Take another look at using the ScriptManager first, and if that _really_ doesn't work for you, then browse the net for .NET AJAX samples.