# Calling JavaScript function from server-side?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

So this seems famous, but with little different.

**JavaScript Function:**

```
function ShowMessage(Message, Title, isAlarm) {
        $("#dtext").html(Message);
        $("span.ui-dialog-title").text(Title);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            open: function(e) {
                var Dia = $(e.target);
                if (isAlarm == true) {
                    Dia.parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "red");
                    Dia.parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("color", "White");
                }
                else {
                    Dia.parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background", "LightSeaGreen");
                    Dia.parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("color", "White");
                }
            },
            show: "blind",
            hide: "clip",
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function(e) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As you see this method fill with Jquery-Code. if this is just java-script, We can use this Code to call that function but in this case this method don't work well.

**C# calling JS Method:**

```
 if (!Pointer.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("message"))
        Pointer.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
            (Pointer.Master.GetType(), "message", "ShowMessage('messageBox','" + Message + "',false);", true);
```

I don't Know  how to resolve this problem. *`I Want just call this Js function from server-side?`*

> ***Edit 1***

Thank for your attention. some guy's want from me describe my problem better. Why I can't ?
Cuz `I don't know what's exactly problem`.

I just can say, I test this program with FireBug and set break-point on first line on JS function but in run time when I call that Js function that break-point `Hit` for a few  Millisecond and then page reload goes complete and nothing happened.

> I'm newbie on JS and jQuery. So Instead hitting down vote plz *try sample program with these Code's and help Me*.

thank Again (specially Stefan, PirateKitten, Widor)

> ***Edit 2***

I made this `Function(JQuery Message Function)` to replace **`Old Function`** which only use simple JS alert. and I must say old version work(even if I call that from server-side with JS-Caller-Function I write).

in this case, even if *`I call new Function(JQ Function) with Js`* in page like :

```
<button type="button" onclick="ShowMessage('hi','title',false)">
  Display Message
</button>
```

It's worked, But **`when call that from server side, Function don't work`**.

Comment: could it be that the function is called to early?. Does this change work? `Pointer.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Pointer.Master.GetType(), "message", "$(function() { ShowMessage('messageBox'," + Message + "',false); }", true);`

Comment: You should probably add what your exact problem is. JS error? Server error? etc.

Comment: You've said "don't work well", what do you actually mean? Is your javascript not rendering out correctly, have you looked to see if you have any JS errors?

Comment: I try this with firebug. Result: that caller method call Js function but nothing happened

Comment: Have you tried @Manuel's solution? That will delay the execution of the function until the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Put simply; you can't.

JavaScript runs clientside, C# runs serverside.

However, you can *generate* JavaScript serverside and output it to the client.

See my answer here: [Call javascript from vb.net code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673795/call-javascript-from-vb-net-code-behind/7673931#7673931)

Comment: I do this, as sample I use simple alert in function and call that function from code behind with that caller method.

Answer (score 1):

Code that is registered with `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` is "rendered" at the end of the page. To be exact in a `script` tag before the `form` close tag. However, the code might run before the DOM tree is fully generated.

Since your `ShowMessage` function access the DOM tree your issue could be related to missing DOM tree elements.

If I do interpret your question correctly there are no JS erros on the page. This chould be as a result of the jquery selector behavior:

```
$("#dtext").html(Message);
```

This will set the HTML of all elements with the id *dtext*. Since there might be no elements with the ID *dtext* yet, `$("#dtext")` will return an empty collection and no actions are taken.

To workaround this issue you can try to run your code in the the jquery document ready event. jQuery fires this event if the page was fully loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ShowMessage('messageBox','" + Message + "', false); }
```

**ServerCode:**

```
 if (!Pointer.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("message"))
        Pointer.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
            (Pointer.Master.GetType(), "message", "$(document).ready(function() {ShowMessage('messageBox','" + Message + "',false); }", true);
```

Comment: reflected the changes in the question.

Comment: your solution Didn't work , but +1 for pointing to Dom Tree and Using JQuery Event

Comment: @Rev: you should try to give a better explanation of your problem. What exactly is not working. "but in this case this method don't work well." is a rather moderate problem description. That's why your answer has three downvotes...

Comment: Ok. What happens if replace all the code in the `ShowMessage` function with a simple `alert("foo");`? If this works, then try to add line by line of your existing code. Do so to identify the line that is not working. Try to output the results of your jQuery selctions: `console.log($("span.ui-dialog-title").length);` etc.

Answer (score -1):

you can call js function from server side like this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "show", "ShowMessage()",true);
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: plz look at my question this isn't solution