# Validating Data in a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a grid as follows.

```
Course         Fee Amount(dynamic textbox)
------         ----------
  A1             15000 
  A2             5000
```

I have a textbox(outside the grid) `txtTotalFeeAmount` with value say, `30000`. My requirement is that the Fee AMount of each A1 and A2 should be lesser than or equal to 30000. Also `A1+A2` should be lesser than or equal to 30000. How do I do this?

**EDIT**

I tried the following, it doesn't work.

```
For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gvCourseFeesDetails.Rows
        Dim lblFeeHeadAmount As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = gvRow.FindControl("lblFeeHeadAmount")
        'Dim lblTotalFeeAmount As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = gvRow.FindControl("lblTotalFeeAmount")

        totalFeeHead = totalFeeHead + Val(lblFeeHeadAmount.Text)

    Next

    nIndividualFeeHead = Val(txtFeeHeadAmount.Text)
    TotalAmount = totalFeeHead + Val(txtFeeHeadAmount.Text)

    If TotalAmount > Val(txtFeeAmount.Text) Then
        Dim script As String = String.Format("ValidateAmount()")
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID, script, True)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

My javascript function:

```
function ValidateAmount()
    {
        alert('Sum of Fee Head Amount should not exceed the total fee amount entered...!');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try anything? why don't you run a loop `foreach (GridViewRow row in grid.Rows)`??

Comment: Did you try de-bugging? do you really need the `ValidateAmount()` separately? Can do something like [Call javascript from vb.net code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673795/call-javascript-from-vb-net-code-behind)

Comment: @Aishvarya what is your problem here?

Comment: @Terror.Blade: I am not able to edit the values once I save. I should be able to do that, logically

Comment: How are you firing the logic to calculate.