# call javascript function from c# not working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Hello guys i have in my popupscrit.js file this method:

```
function afficherMessageInfo( id, message) {


    //Get the A tag
    alert('executing the client code');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(1000);




}

$('.window .close').live("click", function (event) {
//Cancel the link behavior
event.preventDefault();
$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').live("click", function (event) {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.window').hide();
});
```

i want to show a popup   from a c#  button click event like this:

```
void BtnEnregistrer_btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = "#info";
        string messageInfo = "le dossier a été crée avec succès";


        string script = String.Format("afficherMessageInfo({0},{1})", id, messageInfo);
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
        "afficherMessageInfo", script, true);

    }
```

and the html part:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="popupScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="boxes">
<!-- information -->
    <div id="info" class="window" style="display:none;">
        <div class="info_title">
            <div class="pop_title">Information</div>
            <div class="close_image"><a href="#"class="close"/><img src="images/popups/close.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop_content">
            <div class="pop_message">Etiam vel nisl ante. Mauris congue sodales risus ac cele risque Etiam vel nisl ante.Etiam vel nisl ante.</div>
            <div align="right"><input name="" type="button" value="OK" class="info_bt"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Alerte -->
    <div id="alerte" class="window" style="display:none;">
        <div class="alerte_title">
            <div class="pop_title">Alerte</div>
            <div class="close_image"><a href="#"class="close"/><img src="images/popups/close.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop_content">
            <div class="pop_message">Etiam vel nisl ante. Mauris congue sodales risus ac cele risque Etiam vel nisl ante.Etiam vel nisl ante.</div>
            <div align="right"><input name="" type="button" value="OK" class="alerte_bt"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- validation -->
    <div id="validation" class="window" style="display:none;">
        <div class="validation_title">
            <div class="pop_title">Validation</div>
            <div class="close_image"><a href="#"class="close"/><img src="images/popups/close.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop_content">
            <div class="pop_message">Etiam vel nisl ante. Mauris congue sodales risus ac cele risque Etiam vel nisl ante.Etiam vel nisl ante.</div>
            <div align="right"><input name="" type="button" value="Annuler" class="validation_bt"/> <input name="" type="button" value="OK" class="validation_bt"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- confirmation -->
    <div id="confirmation" class="window" style="display:none;">
        <div class="confirmation_title">
            <div class="pop_title">Demande de Confirmation</div>
            <div class="close_image"><a href="#"class="close"/><img src="images/popups/close.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop_content">
            <div class="pop_message">Etiam vel nisl ante. Mauris congue sodales risus ac cele risque Etiam vel nisl ante.Etiam vel nisl ante.</div>
            <div align="right"><input name="" type="button" value="Exemple 1" class="confirmation_bt"/> <input name="" type="button" value="Exemple 2" class="confirmation_bt"/> <input name="" type="button" value="Exemple 3" class="confirmation_bt"/> <input name="" type="button" value="Annuler" class="confirmation_bt"/> <input name="" type="button" value="OK" class="confirmation_bt"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Masque pour couvrir la page -->
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

what's the pb the alert is not showing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameters you are passing to your javascript function is missing quotes:

The line

```
string script = String.Format("afficherMessageInfo({0},{1})", id, messageInfo);
```

should read

```
string script = String.Format("afficherMessageInfo('{0}','{1}')", id, messageInfo);
```

Comment: it append the "afficherMessageInfo('#info','le dossier a été crée avec succès')" to the end of the document.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a semi-colon  after afficherMessageInfo()...

have you tried debugging this using browser tools?

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this code. To the original poster, is it possible to hire someone who understands Javascript and C#? I ask because for example, your strings are being passed unescaped leaving them open to script injection. Getting this one page working is not your only challenge here.

Comment: What the pb with the code Jason.it's the same code as everywhere check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788330/passing-arguments-to-javascript-function-from-code-behind

Comment: there are many syntax errors in the javascript your code behind is emitting.  your best bet to debug the javascript is run this in chrome, and open the developer tools to determine what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `true` parameter on your `RegisterStartupScript` function call, the reason being that it's already defined in your markup for sure within a `<script></script>` block.

`RegisterStartupScript` has an overload that does not take the `include script block param` at the end.

So change your line to this:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
"afficherMessageInfo", script);
```

Comment: Hi lcarus.the function is defined inside popupscript.js file

Comment: @user594166 but you still have a `<script src="popupscript.js" type="text/javascript">` on your markup. Try removing the true parameter and give it a try. RegisterStartupScript has an overload that does not take the `include script block param` at the end.

Comment: can you write that lcarus in your answer.

Comment: thank you lcarus.it only "afficherMessageInfo('#info','le dossier a été crée avec succès')" to the DOM (in the bottom of the document,afficherMessageInfo('#info',it writes "le dossier a été crée avec succès')" )  this is bizzare

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add `OnClientClick` attribute?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = "#info";
    string messageInfo = "le dossier a été crée avec succès";

    BtnEnregistrer.OnClientClick = String.Format("afficherMessageInfo('{0}','{1}')", id, messageInfo);

}
```

This method will refrain you from a `PostBack` and will give you a popup instantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Round your values before using them since they can result in float.
// Also you have to implicitly add '.px' to them.

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height() + '.px';
var maskWidth = $(window).width() + '.px';

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({
    'width':maskWidth,
    'height':maskHeight
});

var windowH = Math.round(winH/2-$(id).height()/2) + '.px';
var windowW = Math.round(winW/2-$(id).width()/2) + '.px';

$(id).css({
    'top': windowH,
    'left': windowW
});
```