# How to call java script from C# code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an `Enable.js` file that has an `Enable()` function. I want to call this `Enable` function from the C# codebehind. My `.js` file and c# file are in same application.

I have tried this, but it doesn't help me.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "click", "Enable(true)", true);
```

Comment: What happens? Is there a JavaScript error? Is `Enabled(true)` contained in the response HTML? (Remember, that will only happen on the client *after* the response is received.)

Comment: Look into your browser console and tell us if you got any errors.

Comment: what are you actually doing in the enable.js and are you able to see any error..?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
                this,
                typeof(Page),
                "Enable-js",
                ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/Enable.js"));


ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                "Enable(True);", true);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb337005.aspx

Comment: I think ScriptManager is used only when Ajax controls like Update Panel are used.This may not help.

Answer (score 2):

I could see "click" in your code. Hence, I assume that you need to click some button to call Enable(true) function inside Enable.js file

Follow these below steps:

1. Reference your Enable.js file inside `<head>` section like below.

   ```html
   <script src="Scripts/Enable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
2. Enable.js file is given below:

   ```
   function Enable(var){
       alert(val)
   }
   ```
3. To call on `Enable()` function on `Button1`'s click event:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
       Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return Enable('true');");
   }
   ```

Let me know if you need some more help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a nice little function for calling jquery or just general JS in C# based on some VB I saw a while ago.

```
public bool runJQueryCode(string message)
{
    ScriptManager requestSM = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

    if (requestSM != null && requestSM.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), true);
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), true);
    }

    return true;
}

private string getjQueryCode(string jsCodetoRun)
{
    string x = "";

    x += "$(document).ready(function() {";
    x += jsCodetoRun;
    x += " });";

    return x;
}
```

So you can just call runJqueryCode("alert('hey')");

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake here:

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "click", "Enable(true)", true);`

The `Enable(true)` is not possible its literal string **true** that you're trying to pass as parameter.

You should try this way, so it may help.`Its only a sample for understanding`

```
string func = "showSuccessMessage('"+name+"');";
//Pass string as funcion in c#
```

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788330/passing-arguments-to-javascript-function-from-code-behind) will explain calling javascript function with parameter from C# Code behind.

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "xx",   
"<script>test("+x+","+y+");</script>");
```