# How to run backend from unity scripts

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, backend

I have a backend application written in java script that i would like to run and access (start and make requests) trough scripts in Unity. It is meant to create, register and login users in database connected to backend app. How can I do this?

I've tried to call my main function using Script Manager: [How to call java script from C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021117/how-to-call-java-script-from-c-sharp-code) but i can't include it. I have .NET 8.0.

Comment: well Why cant you include it?

Comment: Visual code says that namespace doesn't exist

Comment: how did you add it? did you just fire up code (the least preferred editor) and expect ScriptManager to be something you can use? what did you do to get there?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.